# Reading data from firebase real time database into text view

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I want to read from the firebase real time database and set retrieved data in a textview, here is what I have tried so far.

```
     private DatabaseReference buckybarnz;
 .........
buckybarnz =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(userID).child("chel_sea");
  ValueEventListener eventListener = buckybarnz.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
 @Override
 public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    if (dataSnapshot1 != null) {
        DRive dRive = dataSnapshot1.getValue(DRive.class);
        if (dRive != null) {
            String receipt = dRive.getExt_ref().trim();
            String text = dRive.getTxt_Ref().trim();

            chalwe.setText(text);
            johns.setText(receipt);

        } else {
            String a = "no pending refunds available";
            anthony.setText(a);
            chalwe.setText(a);
            johns.setText(a);
        }
    } else {
            String a = "no pending refunds available";
            anthony.setText(a);
            chalwe.setText(a);
            johns.setText(a);
}
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

}
});
```

Nothing is working, even when there's data in the database nothing happens to the textviews.

Please help, what is the best way to solve this problem, even a solution using the string class method would be beneficial. Below is a view of my database [this is a view of my database, BSQ.... being the userID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsJqp.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsJqp.jpg)

Comment: Please provide a more detailed schema where should be included the upper nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I have accessed the database in a different way compared to you :

```
Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
       Firebase reference1 = new Firebase("https://project-id.firebaseio.com/messages/");  //replace project-id by your project-id
            reference1.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                System.out.println("reference4: data snapshot key"+dataSnapshot.getKey()+"");

                //your code
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Hope this helps

Comment: instead of /messages use your table name. do let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: So for instance how would you retrieve the 'ext_ref' and txt_Ref from database. Because when I put my code under where said 'your code' I receive the error 'attempt to invoke virtual method java.lang.String.trim on null object reference at on child added' this error is on the line 'String text =dRive.getExt_ref().trim();'

Comment: I have explained it further in my second answer, do let me if it works for you or not.

Comment: Now the error is can't convert object of type java.lang.string to type com.chomba.Drive, this error is at the same point of code

Comment: can you please add your Drive class in the question

Comment: Also print the data snapshot response : System.out.println("data snapshot " + dataSnapshot.getValue() + "");

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't have to write the for loop, and this should be your edited code in the onChildAdded() method of my code :

```
if (dataSnapshot != null) {
        DRive dRive = dataSnapshot.getValue(DRive.class);
        if (dRive != null) {
            String receipt = dRive.getExt_ref().trim();
            String text = dRive.getTxt_Ref().trim();

            chalwe.setText(text);
            johns.setText(receipt);

        } else {
            String a = "no pending refunds available";
            anthony.setText(a);
            chalwe.setText(a);
            johns.setText(a);
        }
    } else {
            String a = "no pending refunds available";
            anthony.setText(a);
            chalwe.setText(a);
            johns.setText(a);
}
}
```

Hope this works